# 2D boolean array in P5JS as member variable

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm creating a 2 dimensional boolean array in javascript, more specifically in p5js. This works:

```
var cells = Array.from({ length: 3 }, () => 
    Array.from({ length: 3 }, () => false)
);
console.log(cells)
```

And as expected this creates a 3x3 array of booleans set to false, which I can access and change. However when I create this array as a member variable of a class then the values are always false no matter what:

```
class ExampleClass{
    constructor(){
        this.cells = Array.from({ length: 3 }, () => 
            Array.from({ length: 3 }, () => false)
        );
        this.cells[0][0] = true;
        console.log(this.cells)
    }
}
```

This array would now be false. Even if I do something like this, the array is false again:

```
var cells = Array.from({ length: 3 }, () => 
    Array.from({ length: 3 }, () => false)
);
cells[0][0] = true;
this.cells = cells
console.log(this.cells)
```

I think there is something fundamentally flawed with my understanding of how things are initialized in javascript, sorry if that is the case. How would I remedy this? And make the array a member variable but also be able to change the values within it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're getting those results. With your minimal example I can't reproduce the error:

```js
class ExampleClass{
    constructor(){
        this.cells = Array.from({ length: 3 }, () => 
            Array.from({ length: 3 }, () => false)
        );
        this.cells[0][0] = true;
        console.log(this.cells)
        this.cellSize = 100 / 3;
    }
    draw(){
      for(let i = 0; i < this.cells.length; i++){
        for(let j = 0; j < this.cells[i].length; j++){
          fill(this.cells[i][j] * 255);
          rect(i * this.cellSize, j * this.cellSize, this.cellSize, this.cellSize)
        }
      }
    }
}

function setup(){
  createCanvas(100, 100);
  let example = new ExampleClass();
  example.draw();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.3.1/p5.min.js"></script>
```

Perhaps that's an issue with some browsers or something else in a larger program you may be integrating this ?

Comment: You are right, it is part of a larger piece of code! Your example does work as intended. I will have to check what is causing this, thank you for the tip. Just to double-check, the code I provided would be the correct way of doing this?

Comment: Glad to hear that. That is one of the many correct ways of doing this. To a certain degree, in this context it's a matter of preference. You could have used nested for loops to manually fill in values or something less verbose like: `getBooleanArray = (rows, cols) => new Array(rows).fill(new Array(cols).fill(false));`. It's only for really large data you'd think more about performance